# Wordpress wp-config.php constants are not defined

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm not a Wordpress expert but I have a strange problem with it.
Into the `wp-config.php` file I would like to use something like this:

```
    if (!defined('DB_CONFIGURED')) {

       /// my logic here..

       define('DB_CONFIGURED', true);
    }
```

For each page loaded I noticed that the constants are not defined.
If I try to print the status of my constant or all defined constants (like DB_NAME, etc) these are not defined.

First of all... why is `wp-config` used for all requested pages?

My idea was to set a constant into the `wp-config` file and find it set again at every turn after the first time.

Why?

How can I solve it?

Comment: Where did you define these constants instead? Also, why not call the file with all configuration settings on each request? How would you handle this otherwise?

Comment: I'm integrating the AWS Secrets manager to download the DB credentials and store them into the wp constants as used into the wp-config. For example, after downloading the secret content I'll store  define('DB_PASSWORD', get_from_secret);
To avoid to download the secret for each request, my idea was to define a flag constant to skip the download if the secret is already downloaded.

Comment: In PHP (and thus WordPress), all variables, including constants and globals, are scoped to the current request. This means that any dynamic `define` calls will be thrown away once the request goes away. You need to get the credentials to a persistent location. One option is to pick a dedicated custom file, call `is_file()` on it, and if it doesn't exist, do your logic and then create it with those constants. Another option is environment variables. Your code should probably block so that multiple requests don't invoke your logic concurrently.